# How to define an object of a templated class type?

Tags: c++

If I have this structure:

```
namespace A
{
    template <Class T>
    struct Point
    {
        Point<T>(T x_, T y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

        Point<T>() : x(0), y(0) {}

         T x;
         T y;
    }
}
```

How might I define an object from the Point struct?

I tried:

```
A::Point point;
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Don't be vague, be an ace; learn to write a proper testcase! http://sscce.org/ http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml http://tinyurl.com/so-hints "Does not work" is *not* an error description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i.e.:

```
 A::Point<int> point;
 A::Point<int> point(1,1);
```

but first fix errors (note case for 'class' and missing semicolons):

```
namespace A
{
    template <class T>
    struct Point
    {
        Point<T>(T x_, T y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

        Point<T>() : x(0), y(0) {}

         T x;
         T y;
    };
}
```

Comment: D'oh beat me to it by 29 seconds! There's a stray ) in your first line though.

Comment: <pedant>The semicolon after the end of the namespace isn't needed</pedant>

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a few syntax errors here. If you correct your code to:

```
namespace A
{
    template <class T> // Class is lowercase
    struct Point
    {
        Point(T x_, T y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {} // No need for <T>

        Point() : x(0), y(0) {} // No need for <T>

         T x;
         T y;
    }; // Semi colon
}
```

Then:

`A::Point<int> point;`

is valid. You need to tell it what the template parameter is though, there's no way to deduce it automatically in this case.

Comment: As a general style point it's probably a good habit to use const T& x_, const T& y_ in the ctor for uses like that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the [template argument](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_arguments.htm) when instantiating the structure, e.g.:

```
A::Point<double> point;
```

Answer (score 0):

`A::Point<int> point;` for example, or `A::Point<float> point;` - you need to specify the type to specialize with. Otherwise how would the compiler know which type `T` is?

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need to add a semicolon after the definition of `struct Point`. The to declare an instance of type `A::Point<int>`:

```
A::Point<int> point;
```